# SQL Server SSRS Reporting

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have to make a report in BIDS using SQL sever 2008. Below is the mock-up of report I have to develop, I am working on it for last 2 days. But I can't figure it out, how to build query or stored procedure for it.

[image]

`I need you guys suggestion that how would it be possible to achieve this kind of report:Should I use Queries/SubQueries or Stored Procedures ??`

I have tried it with Subquery, and now struggling with Stored Procedure but I am stuck. I cant figure it out.

**Details:**

`Total Leads = 12,   out of 12, 8 are Open and 4 are Closed`

Comment: You need to create a query that returns the whole result set. The grouping for total, open and closed happens in the report and not the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a stored procedure to return your data in the given format. It may need input parameters but essentially will return the above columns (without the pretty column heading merging).

Create your SSRS report and point it at the Stored Procedure as the source. You can then change the formatted results of the query in the report designer.

[See this post for an example how to select a Stored Procedure as the datasource](http://www.phpring.com/how-to-create-report-in-ssrs-using-stored-procedure/)